# MYSQL: How can I create a MySQL table so, that a field's default value is the output of a function

Tags: sql, mysql, replace, ddl

**QUESTION** How can I create a MySQL table so, that a field's default value is the output of a function.

Can it be done without an insert trigger?

**BACKGROUND:** Some entities and the groups they belong to need to be observed on a daily basis.

To do that I created the following MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE entity (
    entity_id  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    group_id   VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    first_seen DATE        NOT NULL,
    last_seen  DATE        NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (entity_id,group_id)
)
```

A script parses the entity logs on a daily basis and writes to to entity_raw, I then want to update the tables using

```
REPLACE INTO entity (entity_id,group_id,last_seen) 
SELECT entity_id,group_id,record_date 
  FROM entity_raw 
 WHERE (record_date = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Naturally I get an error when inserting new (entity_id,group_id) pairs, since first_seen may not be NULL...

Can this be done in one statement, short of using a trigger (I dislike them, too surprising for maintenance)

or do I need to select for existance first, then insert/update accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I came up with this .. it solves my "problem", but not the question I asked :-(

```
REPLACE INTO entity (entity_id,group_id,first_seen,last_seen) 
SELECT r.entity_id              AS entity_id
     , r.group_id               AS group_id
     , ISNULL( e.first_seen
              ,r.record_date
             )                  AS first_seen
     , r.record_date            AS last_seen
  FROM entity_raw r
  LEFT OUTER JOIN entity e ON (    r.entity_id=e.entity_id 
                               AND r.group_id=e.group_id
                              )
 WHERE (record_date = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

The initial insert needs to be done with the where clause disabled (there were already 5weeks of data in the entity_raw table)

Answer (score 2):

No, what you're asking isn't possible without triggers. The only example in MySQL where a field can be assigned a default value from a function is the TIMESTAMP type that can have CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default.

Comment: +1 for answering my question .. luckily there is another way to solve the underlying problem

Answer (score 1):

To be honest it's pretty much impossible to combine an update or insert into one statement.

If you are using a script, I would do as you suggested. First check for existence, then update or insert accordingly.

Otherwise a trigger or stored procedure would do the job.

Comment: +1 for answering my question .. luckily there is another way to solve the underlying problem

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `TIMESTAMP` data type, which allows a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but that would set it to `NOW()` and not to a day ago.

So, I would rather use use an `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement:

```
INSERT INTO entity (entity_id,group_id,first_seen,last_seen) 
SELECT entity_id,group_id,record_date, record_date 
    FROM entity_raw 
    WHERE (record_date = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_seen = VALUES(last_seen)
```

with a unique index en `entity_id` and/or `group_id`. This will overwrite only `last_seen` when an existing row is found.

Comment: Hm .. You answered my question and tried to solve my problem .. see my own answer ..

Comment: Yes, but maybe you are using an old mysql version that doesn't support this, etc (if so edit your question accordingly). So you can vote up an suposedly helpful answer, but you should try first, and then if it works accept it as *your chosen working answer* to your question.